# How do you call a function after a timeout is complete? Timeout is triggered by a click event (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

So I want to call 'this.breakCheck();' after the timeout is complete. Right now I'm calling it with every iteration and my program is working, but ideally I'd like to be called only once after the timeout completes.

```
public startBreak(){
  for(let i = this.breakSeconds; i > 0; i--){
    this.$timeout(() =>{ this.breakSeconds -= 1; this.breakCheck();}, 1000 * i);
    }
}
```

Previously I had it here

```
    public startBreak(){
    for(let i = this.breakSeconds; i > 0; i--){
        this.$timeout(() =>{ this.breakSeconds -= 1;}, 1000 * i);
    }
     this.breakCheck();
}
```

But because 'startBreak()' is called by a click event, it just ran immediately.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Spec:

- `breakCheck` only called once
- only called after `breakSeconds`

Simples:

```
public startBreak(){
    this.$timeout(()=>this.breakCheck(), this.breakSeconds * 1000);
}
```